# Best way to convert pdf files to tiff files

Tags: pdf, image, tiff

I have around 1000 pdf filesand I need to convert them to 300 dpi tiff files. What is the best way to do this? If there is an SDK or something or a tool that can be scripted that would be ideal.

Comment: This is the solution that I use:

[Pdf to Tiff using Xpdf's pdftoppm and LibTIFF's ppm2tiff and tiffcp (optional, only if multipage)][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12868254/551460

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample ? maybe using powershell script..

Comment: @Kiquenet I posted one solution using powershell. See it below...

Comment: Use Ghrostscript as `gs -q -dNOPAUSE -r300x300 -sDEVICE=tiff24nc -sOutputFile=output.tif input.pdf -c quit` (on Windows the command is `gswin32c`) to produce 300x300 dpi and 24bit color image

Comment: Best way to convert PDF files to TIFF files? For sure: use `pdftoppm`, as follows: `mkdir images && pdftoppm -tiff -r 300 mypdf.pdf images/pg`. See here for details, usage, & more info: https://askubuntu.com/questions/150100/extracting-embedded-images-from-a-pdf/1187844#1187844.

Comment: This is somewhat of a cop-out answer, but I tried Ghostscript and didn't have good success. On the other hand, Adobe Acrobat had an option to export the PDF as `.tif` files, and it worked perfectly for my needs. It output settings can also be adjusted.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Use Imagemagick, or better yet, Ghostscript.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-graf2/#N101C2 has an example for imagemagick:

```
convert foo.pdf pages-%03d.tiff
```

http://www.asmail.be/msg0055376363.html has an example for ghostscript:

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -sOutputFile=a.tif foo.pdf -c quit
```

I would install ghostscript and read the man page for gs to see what exact options are needed and experiment.

Comment: ghostscript works really good, as far as i understand imagemagick is reusing ghostscript for pdf operations. Is this correct?

Comment: that's what I hear, but I'm not an expert on ImageMagick internals ;)

Comment: does imagemagick handle multipage pdf --> tiff properly?

Comment: wow, ghostscript really needs to clean up its command line interface!

Comment: `imagemagick` worked well without configuration. I could not configure `ghostscript` properly to get a high resolution colour image.

Comment: `convert foo.pdf pages-%03d.tiff` produces horribly-low-quality images. How do we increase the resolution to be what is already in the pdf, so no resolution is lost?

Comment: After tons and tons and tons of research, here's what I've decided is best: `pdftoppm`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/150100/extracting-embedded-images-from-a-pdf/1187844#1187844. Also, in case the goal if making TIFFs here is to use `tesseract` to convert the PDF to a *searchable* pdf via OCR, I've done that now too and written an interface to do it in one step: `pdf2searchablepdf input.pdf`--see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/473843/how-to-turn-a-pdf-into-a-text-searchable-pdf/1187881#1187881.

Answer (score 45):

Using GhostScript from the command line, I've used the following in the past:

on Windows:

`gswin32c -dNOPAUSE -q -g300x300 -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output_file_name.tif input_file_name.pdf`

on *nix:

`gs -dNOPAUSE -q -g300x300 -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output_file_name.tif input_file_name.pdf`

For a large number of files, a simple batch/shell script could be used to convert an arbitrary number of files...

Comment: +1. Useful command. But my color figure is outputting in black and white. Any idea why?

Comment: `-sDEVICE=tiffg4` is a black and white fax compression model. See: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/doc/AFPL/8.00/Devices.htm#TIFF

Comment: Most of the time you want to convert a pdf to TIFF images of 300x300 dpi, not 300x300 size. For this reason, replace `-g` switch with `-r`: `gswin32c -dNOPAUSE -q -r300x300 ...`

Comment: Thanks @HairyFotr. For anyone else visiting, you should be using `-sDEVICE=tiff24nc` for 24-bit RGB, or `-sDEVICE=tiff12nc` for 12-bit (8/4 bits per channel, respectively).

Answer (score 19):

I wrote a little powershell script to go through a directory structure and convert all pdf files to tiff files using ghostscript. Here is my script:

```
$tool = 'C:\Program Files\gs\gs8.63\bin\gswin32c.exe'
$pdfs = get-childitem . -recurse | where {$_.Extension -match "pdf"}

foreach($pdf in $pdfs)
{

    $tiff = $pdf.FullName.split('.')[0] + '.tiff'
    if(test-path $tiff)
    {
        "tiff file already exists " + $tiff
    }
    else        
    {   
        'Processing ' + $pdf.Name        
        $param = "-sOutputFile=$tiff"
        & $tool -q -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=tiffg4 $param -r300 $pdf.FullName -c quit
    }
}
```

Comment: After 7 years, this continues to be helpful! I would only add that a person who has no PowerShell experience, you need to: 1. Edit the $tool value to match the path and version on your system. 2. Open PowerShell and cd to the directory where the PDFs are stored. 3. Paste the code into the PowerShell window. I needed to press enter a couple times after to get it to run. Thanks gyurisc

Answer (score 9):

1) Install GhostScript

2) Install ImageMagick

3) Create "Convert-to-TIFF.bat" (Windows XP, Vista, 7) and use the following line:

```
for %%f in (%*) DO "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.6.4-Q16\convert.exe" -density 300 -compress lzw %%f %%f.tiff
```

Dragging any number of single-page PDF files onto this file will convert them to compressed TIFFs, at 300 DPI.

Comment: GhostScript is required ? If I only install ImageMagick ?

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: How can we change color to greyscale or any other similar colors? Also it repeats the file name while saving. I'm using it on Windows 10

Answer (score 7):

using python this is what I ended up with

```py
import os
os.popen(' '.join([
                   self._ghostscriptPath + 'gswin32c.exe', 
                   '-q',
                   '-dNOPAUSE',
                   '-dBATCH',
                   '-r300',
                   '-sDEVICE=tiff12nc',
                   '-sPAPERSIZE=a4',
                   '-sOutputFile=%s %s' % (tifDest, pdfSource),
                   ]))
```

Comment: Generally you'll want to use subprocess for this. os.popen is considered deprecated. The syntax is nearly the same.

Answer (score 3):

How about pdf2tiff? http://python.net/~gherman/pdf2tiff.html

Comment: this does not handle multipage tiffs yet, so unfortunately this is no go for me. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 3):

ABCPDF can do so as well -- check out http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf6net/default.html

Answer (score 3):

The PDF Focus .Net can do it in such way:

**1.** ***PDF to TIFF***

```
SautinSoft.PdfFocus f = new SautinSoft.PdfFocus();    

string pdfPath = @"c:\My.pdf";

string imageFolder = @"c:\images\";

f.OpenPdf(pdfPath);

if (f.PageCount > 0)
{
    //Save all PDF pages to image folder as tiff images, 200 dpi
    int result = f.ToImage(imageFolder, "page",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff, 200);
}
```

**2.** ***PDF to Multipage-TIFF***

```
//Convert PDF file to Multipage TIFF file

SautinSoft.PdfFocus f = new SautinSoft.PdfFocus();

string pdfPath = @"c:\Document.pdf";
string tiffPath = @"c:\Result.tiff";

f.OpenPdf(pdfPath);

if (f.PageCount > 0)
{
    f.ToMultipageTiff(tiffPath, 120) == 0)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(tiffPath);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

https://pypi.org/project/pdf2tiff/

You could also use pdf2ps, ps2image and then convert from the resulting image to tiff with other utilities (I remember 'paul' [paul - Yet another image viewer (displays PNG, TIFF, GIF, JPG, etc.])

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: work for product I am recommending

Atalasoft has a .NET library that can [convert PDF to TIFF](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/net-tiff-pdf-sdk.aspx) -- we are a partner of FOXIT, so the PDF rendering is very good.

Answer (score 2):

Required ghostscript & tiffcp
Tested in Ubuntu

```
import os

def pdf2tiff(source, destination):
    idx = destination.rindex('.')
    destination = destination[:idx]
    args = [
    '-q', '-dNOPAUSE', '-dBATCH',
    '-sDEVICE=tiffg4',
    '-r600', '-sPAPERSIZE=a4',
    '-sOutputFile=' + destination + '__%03d.tiff'
    ]
    gs_cmd = 'gs ' + ' '.join(args) +' '+ source
    os.system(gs_cmd)
    args = [destination + '__*.tiff', destination + '.tiff' ]
    tiffcp_cmd = 'tiffcp  ' + ' '.join(args)
    os.system(tiffcp_cmd)
    args = [destination + '__*.tiff']
    rm_cmd = 'rm  ' + ' '.join(args)
    os.system(rm_cmd)    
pdf2tiff('abc.pdf', 'abc.tiff')
```

Answer (score 1):

I like PDFTIFF.com   to [convert PDF to TIFF](https://www.pdftiff.com/pdf-2-tiff.html), it can handle unlimited pages

Comment: This site no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe also try this? [PDF Focus](http://www.sautinsoft.com/products/pdf-focus/index.php)

This .Net library allows you to solve the problem :)

This code will help (Convert 1000 PDF files to 300-dpi TIFF files in C#):

```
    SautinSoft.PdfFocus f = new SautinSoft.PdfFocus();

    string[] pdfFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"d:\Folder with 1000 pdfs\", "*.pdf");
    string folderWithTiffs = @"d:\Folder with TIFFs\";

    foreach (string pdffile in pdfFiles)
    {
        f.OpenPdf(pdffile);

        if (f.PageCount > 0)
        {
            //save all pages to tiff files with 300 dpi
            f.ToImage(folderWithTiffs, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pdffile), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff, 300);
        }
        f.ClosePdf();
    }
```

Comment: You should specify "pdf focus" comes with a price.