# How to compare two pdf files?

Tags: pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tool to compare large numbers of PDF files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145657/tool-to-compare-large-numbers-of-pdf-files)

I have generated two pdf files 
1.MNTR305K.PRT.pdf (1862 pages) of 2760 KB
2.MNTR305K.PRT.pdf (1862 pages) of 7345 KB
 I saw each pdf file by comparing it's content and fonts. I found everything is same. I don't know why the why the second file took more size than the first one.Does any one help me how to find the difference.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> I have generated two pdf files

What are you using to generate the PDF?

If you are using iText api, then;

- Always use setFormFlattening before closing the stamp.
- If you are copying / merging pdf using iText then use freeReader before closing the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Probably down the way the PDF creator is storing/compressing the page data. Have you had a look inside at the structures with Acrobat Pro?

Answer (score 1):

Acrobat has a "space auditor" that can tell you if the size increase is caused by images, fonts, format overhead, etc. Open the "PDF optimizer" and click on the 'Audit space usage..." button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [i-net PDF content comparer](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/pdf-content-comparer) to compare 2 PDF files. It's specifically for finding "hidden" differences that are hard to make out with the naked eye.

Comment: Please refrain from promoting proprietary software.

Answer (score 0):

BeyondCompare work for you?

http://www.scootersoftware.com/

Comment: You should probably note that it's commercial. And I'm guessing that's not gonna work for the OP.