# Is there a way of comparing text from two PDF files in Javascript or Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf

Simple question:

Does anyone know if is there a (simple) way of comparing text from two PDF files with Javascript or Angular?

Or at least a way of get the plain text from them and search for the line numbers for example to show a visual comparison of both files?

I need to implement something similar to the git plugins comparison, or BeyondCompare for example inside my project, so I would need the code or the tool to integrate it into my Angular project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible to duplicate **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145657/tool-to-compare-large-numbers-of-pdf-files**.

Comment: @Kadioo it's not the same question, I'm asking for Javascript or Angular code to add to my project, the other question is asking about a tool to compare large amounts of pdf in general, not with a specific technology, not necessarily code. I've already seen that question, no solution there for my case. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979431/how-to-compare-two-pdf-files

Comment: Same answer as before @Kadioo there is not a Javascript or Angular solution there