# Compare PDF documents in Adobe Acrobat via SDK

Tags: c#, pdf, compare, document, acrobat

We are planning on implementing a solution for comparing different revisions of a PDF document in our .Net Windows Forms application. In Adobe Acrobat there is a nice feature for comparing two documents, but I have not been able to find any information about whether it is possible to create a plug-in (or something else) to this feature from our application.

I would really appreciate it if any of you could point me in the direction to how I should go about to make such a solution.

I have also looked at other threads here at Stackoverflow for comparing PDF documents, particularly these threads:

[How to compare two PDF-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145657/how-to-compare-two-pdf-files)

[PDF-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210029/pdf-libraries)

I did not really find a good solution there for a library or SDK letting us create a good solution for comparing PDF-documents in a way which is easy to understand for users of the system.

Do you know any good solutions to solve this problem?

All help appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the pdf files? or you just want to make the compare without knowing it. If you know the pdf files, you can use variables values on the specific fields and compare the values  between files, instead comparing the entire pdf file.