# Is there a way to test PDF outputs in acceptance / e2e tests?

Tags: pdf, e2e-testing

In order to test the results of most of my business requirements I need to find out if a PDF is rendered correctly.

A typical test involves a few UI interactions with an Web application and the download of the resulting PDF.

Then the results should be compared to their expectations.

Is there a testing framework capable of examining a PDF?

Comment: Take a look at the [testutils](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/tree/master/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/testutils) that ship with iText and at the way we test PDF files in our [test classes](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/tree/master/src/test/java/com/itextpdf).

Answer (score 1):

There are already lots and lots answers on StackOverflow dealing with similar questions.

Look at this list:
￼

- **[How to unit test a Python function that draws PDF graphics?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4675060/359307)** (StackOverflow)
- **[Visual diff PDF files in order to determine pixel perfectness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12466892/359307)** (StackOverflow)
- **[How to compare two PDF files through command line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11005340/359307)**  (StackOverflow)
- **[Comparison of two PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6737451/359307)** (StackOverflow)
- **[PDF compare on Linux command line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6494387/359307%10)** (StackOverflow)