# ImageMagick compare executable: unrecognized option `-metric' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2060

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I tried to use `apt-get install imagemagick` command to install ImageMagick on my Debian Wheezy. But when I try to diff images, I get following error:

```
root@work:/home/tests/YAML_SHOTS/en-us# convert 1.png 2.png -metric RMSE -compare 3.png
convert.im6: unrecognized option `-metric' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2060.
```

Secondly, I tried to install ImageMagick from binary source (described here: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php#unix). But it does not install the `convert` executable command.

How can I fix that?

P.S. If I remove `-metric` option, I get one more error:

```
convert.im6: unrecognized option `-compare' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1107.
```

Comment: What's the output of `identify -list metric`?

Comment: What's the output of `convert -version`?

Comment: @emcconville AE
Fuzz
MAE
MEPP
MSE
NCC
PAE
PHASH
PSNR
RMSE

Comment: @KurtPfeifle (compiled) `ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2014-10-27` and i've also tried to install `6.7.7.10-5+deb7u3` via  `apt-get install imagemagick`

Answer (score 2):

Use the [compare](http://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php#compare) utility directly.

```sh
compare 1.png 2.png -metric RMSE 3.png
```

But if you want to generate a image diff without sending the metrics to STDERR, define the `-metric` and `-compare` before the image stack.

```sh
convert -metric RMSE -compare 1.png 2.png 3.png
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your ImageMagick version is a fairly recent one, try this command:

```
 compare -metric phash 1.png 2.png delta.png

   7.61662
```

The returned pHash value of `7.61662` indicates, that there was indeed some difference in the compared image, and that the `delta.png` will show some red highlighted pixels.

The red pixels indicate there is a difference in the color values of the respective pixels in the two compared images. White pixels indicate identical color values. The grayed-out, light color background of the delta.png is derived from the first image, in order to help identify better the differences in more complex images. If you do not want the background, run this modified command:

```
 compare -metric phash 1.png 2.png -compose src delta.png
```

[image: <code>1.png</code> (left), <code>2.png</code> (center) and <code>delta.png</code> (right)]

Above illustration depicts `1.png` (left), `2.png` (center) and `delta.png` (right).

Compare this to

```
 compare -metric phash 1.png 1.png delta2.png

   0
```

Here there is no difference, the pHash value is `0`, and the `delta2.png` doesn't show any red pixels:

[image: <code>1.png</code> (left), <code>1.png</code> (center) and <code>delta2.png</code> (right)]

Above illustration depicts `1.png` (left), `1.png` (center) and `delta2.png` (right).

---

By default, the `compare` command will run with 72 PPI. If you need a higher resolution (for example, when comparing PDF pages), add `-density 300` as the first parameter to get 300 PPI.