# Ghostscript PDF -> TIFF conversion is awful for me, people rave about it, I alone look sullen

Tags: pdf, image-manipulation, tiff, ghostscript

My stomach churns when I see this kind of output.

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e1097a5a10.jpg

and this was my command
as suggested by [Best way to convert pdf files to tiff files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75500/best-way-to-convert-pdf-files-to-tiff-files#221341)

```
gswin32c.exe -q -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -sOutputFile=a.tif a.pdf -c quit
```

What am I doing wrong?

(commercial products will not be considered)

Comment: -r800? That is a DPI of 800x800, surely that can't be correct.

Comment: image sample is broken...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

tiffg4 is a black&white output device.
You should use tiff24nc or tiff12nc as the output device colour PDFs - see [ghostscript output devices](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/doc/AFPL/8.00/Devices.htm#TIFF).
These will be uncompressed but you could put the resulting TIFFs through imagemagick or similar to resave as compressed TIFF.

Comment: Thanks for the colour information. After including Philho's advice about resolution im finding my tif shooting up to 20+ megs. This is way beyond. Making use of imagemagick would reduce this?

Comment: Yes, ImageMagick (and many other image manipulation tools) can convert uncomressed TIFF to compressed TIFF.  Are you sure you need TIFF?  24-bit PNG is a pretty good choice for screen capture.

Comment: must be tiff sadly, the whole backend system is setup for tiff, a change and the whole thing comes down kicking and screaming. Also i just found out it must be black and white... interfacing with legacy systems can be a little of a headache... pdf would be the best.

Answer (score 11):

I have been using ImageMagick for quite a sometime. It's very nice tool with a lot of features.

Install [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) and run following command. This is what I used on Linux, you may have to replace `convert` with the correct one.

Below command converts PDFs to **CCITT Group 3** standard TIFs (Fax standard):

```
convert -define quantum:polarity=min-is-white \
        -endian MSB \
        -units PixelsPerInch \
        -density 204x196 \
        -monochrome \
        -compress Fax \
        -sample 1728 \
        "input.pdf" "output.tif"
```

Also you may use [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/), it is also similar to ImageMagick, but ImageMagick more concerns with quality than speed.

Comment: This is by far the best option I have seen in a long time for converting a text based PDF to TIFF while maintaining decent quality and a low file size. Switching the compress option to Group4 reduces the file size even further, and I maybe seeing things, but it looks like the quality actually got even better.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guys this is what I ended up with

```
     os.popen(' '.join([
                       self._ghostscriptPath + 'gswin32c.exe', 
                       '-q',
                       '-dNOPAUSE',
                       '-dBATCH',
                       '-r800',
                       '-sDEVICE=tiffg4',
                       '-sPAPERSIZE=a4',
                       '-sOutputFile=%s %s' % (tifDest, pdfSource),
                       ]))
```

Answer (score 2):

setori's command does not specify the resolution to use for the *tiffg4* output. The consequence is: Ghostscript will use its default setting for that output, which is 204x196dpi.

In order to increase the resolution to 600dpi, add a `-r600` commandline parameter:

```
gswin32c.exe ^
   -o output.tiff ^
   -sDEVICE=tiffg4 ^
   -r600 ^
    input.pdf
```

Also note that TIFFG4 is the standard fax format and as such it uses black+white/grayscale only, but no colors.

**@jeff:** Have you ever tried the `-dDITHERPPI=<lpi>` parameter with Ghostscript? (Reasonable values for *lpi* are N/5 to N/20, where N is the resolution in dpi. So for `-r600` use try with `-dDITHERPPI=30` to `dDITHERPPI=120`).

Answer (score 2):

Like other posts suggested, use a color format (e.g. -sDEVICE=tiff24nc) and specify a higher resolution (e.g. -r600x600):

```
gswin32c.exe -q -dNOPAUSE -r600 -sDEVICE=tiff24nc -sOutputFile=a.tif a.pdf -c quit
```

Comment: Please do not add an answer when other posts already contain that answer. Instead, upvote the existing post which you agree with.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite nice for a fax! ;-)

danio's answer is probably the best, if you need a color copy.

I notice also, from the linked thread, that you omitted to specify DPI for the output, hence the bad look... If you need pure dithered B&W, you should use a higher resolution.

I also got a good looking image using [NConvert](http://pagesperso-orange.fr/pierre.g/xnview/en_nconvert.html)

```
nconvert -page 1 -out tiff -dpi 200 -c 2 -o c.tif FMD.pdf
```

I mention it for the record, because I think you need a license to redistribute it (it is free for personal use otherwise).

Comment: Not going with Nvonvert, it cant read my pdf document I gave it to convert

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with fax pages.

I was using Imagick in php and this command fixed the way it looked.

```
$Imagick->blackThresholdImage('grey');
```

I didn't see any threshold option using 'gs' but convert may also work for you.

```
convert a.pdf -threshold 60% a.tif
```