# VB dLL to convert pdf to tiff

Tags: vb6

Is any dll or ocx available to convert pdf to tif in vb 6? Preferably free.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the COM support of **ImageMagick**:

> http://www.imagemagick.org/script/ImageMagickObject.php

Comment: Can I have any free dll to use in my project

Comment: Yes, ImageMagick is "free". It comes with a GPL-compatible license.

Answer (score 0):

I found that ImageMagick doesn't have the ability to convert PDFs to Tif by default.  You have to download another program called Ghostscript (which is free under GPL).

Download here: http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html

See this thread for how to use the command line: [Best way to convert pdf files to tiff files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75500/best-way-to-convert-pdf-files-to-tiff-files)

Then use the Shell to the command with the parameter to convert the file to tif.