# iOS pdf in a UIWebview, error FT_Select_Charmap failed

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf, uiwebview, load

I've looked around for a while now but can't seem to find an answer. I load my pdf into a UIWebview using;

`[myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:path ofType:@"pdf"]]]];`

In the console i get the following errors;

FT_Select_Charmap failed: error 6

FT_Select_Charmap failed: error 38

Now this doesn't cause the app to crash as far as i can tell, but i would like to know the cause.

Thanks

Comment: I am facing exactly same problem? Were you able to fix it? Please help if you have fixed it.

Comment: @iMobileDev Unfortunately not, i ended up re scanning the problem pdf's and re creating them. If you find anything please let me know.

Comment: How did you re-create the pdfs? I havn't got any solution yet.

Comment: @iMobileDev I used this technique http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75500/best-way-to-convert-pdf-files-to-tiff-files#221341 to output the pdf as images. Then used adobe pro to recreate the pdf. Adobe pro isn't free but i'm sure there are other free ways to create a pdf from images.

Comment: Thanks Mike, will find out more. But meanwhile if you find some solution please reply to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15263805/llalckmyriadpro-semiboldit-ft-select-charmap-failed-error-6