# Return TIFF in Connect Service

Tags: docusignapi

Is there any chance the option of returning a TIFF image will be a configurable option in the connect profile any time soon?  We are working with a few firms that require TIFF for FINRA compliance.

Thanks,

Russell

Answer (score 1):

Upon import into the DocuSign system, all file formats are converted to PDF format -- and will remain in PDF format from that point on. This means that any files you retrieve from DocuSign (via Connect, via API, manually via the web console) will always be in PDF format. This is not likely to change.

I suspect that you'd be able to receive the PDF files via Connect and convert them to TIFF format via some automated process. Although I don't personally have any experience with this (automatically converting PDF to TIFF), a quick Google search turns up lots of possibilities...for example: [Best way to convert pdf files to tiff files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75500/best-way-to-convert-pdf-files-to-tiff-files).

Comment: I understand that this is possible and I have worked with many different pdf to tiff converters which all have their place and work well.  The issue here is we can NOT modify the signed document which is returned from DocuSign for compliance reasons.  As soon as the document is run through the conversion from pdf to tiff it is NOT the original signed copy we receive back and it is no longer compliant.   I am looking for answers for my original question as to whether this will be or has been discussed at docusign as functionality.  I am not looking for workarounds.  Thank You...

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification. In that case, I'd suggest that you follow-up with DocuSign (via your account manager if you have one, or if you don't have an AM then via the Community Forum -- http://community.docusign.com/ -- there's an area for "Product Ideas & Feedback"). Stackoverflow is for technical how-to Q&A -- it's not the appropriate venue to discuss product roadmap.