# ImageMagick convert issues

Tags: imagemagick

I have been using the batch method to convert any number of PDFs to any other format in any DPI ([Best way to convert pdf files to tiff files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75500/best-way-to-convert-pdf-files-to-tiff-files)).

ImageMagick was updated (I run ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16), and I though the old command:

```
convert -density 300 -compress LZW testfile.pdf testfile.jpg
```

could just be changed to:

```
magick -density 300 -compress LZW testfile.pdf testfile.jpg
```

Both the 'density' and the 'compress' functionality appear in the new manual... It does create a jpg, however, the DPI is 96 (default?) and it seems that the actual dimensions of the figure increases a lot.

(The actual text in the .bat file is

```
for %%f in (%*) DO "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16\magick.exe" -density 300 -compress LZW %%f %%f.jpg
```

but the issue also appears when I run the simplified code above...

Comment: This may be a more appropriate question for SuperUser

Comment: You seem confused - I think your command creates a JPG from a PDF not a PDF from a JPEG. You have the input and output files switched and also mis-spell `LZW`

Comment: Oops, I see why you think I am confused. Fixed the text now.