# How to convert multiple pages of single pdf in to one TIFF file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, imagemagick

How to convert multiple pages of single pdf into one pdf

```
import os 
os.system('convert 1902CAN00048.pdf outpit1.tiff -alpha Off shell=True')
```

error `255`

Comment: Check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75500/best-way-to-convert-pdf-files-to-tiff-files

Answer (score 0):

That `shell=True` seems out of place. It's a parameter you'd use with `subprocess.Popen`, not `os.system`.

Have you tried

```py
import os
os.system('convert 1902CAN00048.pdf outpit1.tiff -alpha off')
```

?

Does `convert 1902CAN00048.pdf outpit1.tiff -alpha off` work on the command line as you expect?